# Is it possible to use the same EndPoint for several Microsoft Bots

Tags: c#, botframework, skypedeveloper

I'm trying the new Microsoft Bot Framework to build Skype Bots.
I was wondering if it's possible to register the same EndPoint for several Bots?

I saw the Microsoft examples and they use the web.config to store the:

```
<add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="GUID" />
<add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="PASSWORD" />
```

And using the `[BotAuthentication]` attribute to resolve everything.

If the same endpoing can be reused for several Bots, how should I handle the authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Multi tenant implementation - possible solution

Change the route of the messages endpoint to take a wildcard like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    [Route("messages/{*wildcard}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
```

Implement a multi tenant bot authentication attribute which will take the application id from the last url segment (or a lookup to fetch it from a database).

e.g. http://localhost:3979/messages/your-bot-app-id-or-key

```
[MultiTentantBotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
```

Implementation

```
public class MultiTentantBotAuthenticationAttribute : BotAuthentication
{
    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.MicrosoftAppId = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Segments.Last();

        await base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

If you need the code in your bot to know which app it is operating in you could pass it in via userdata like so:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    [Route("messages/{*wildcard}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        var botId = Request.RequestUri.Segments.Last(); // Validate against your database / configuration

        try
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                // https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/stateapi.html

                var stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
                BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
                userData.SetProperty("ApplicationAccountBotId", botId);
                await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);

                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => actionDialog);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            await logger.ErrorAsync(exception);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

You can then access user data in a dialog / bot code.

Comment: This works well. For info, in BotFramework 3.13.1 the method to override is now called OnActionExecutingAsync. Also, in order to have the authentication preserved when using the Conversation class, you need to update its container to retrieve the MicrosoftAppCredentials from the HttpContext user identity, I added this code where I register my Autofac modules `Conversation.UpdateContainer(cbuilder =>
            {
                cbuilder.Register(c => ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).GetCredentialsFromClaims()).AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            });`

Answer (score 0):

*Can I have multiple bot framework registrations for the same web service (bot) and same endpoint?*

If this is what you mean, the answer is no, at least not with the Bot Builder SDK. For one endpoint, you can only use one set of credentials. I see no problem with using the same Microsoft App ID (and password) for several bot registrations, but currently this is not supported.

What is your use case? You want to have multiple channel identities (e.g. on Facebook) for the same bot? If you really need this, I believe you can achieve this by implementing authentication yourself (instead of relying on the SDK for this).

**UPDATE**

An easy workaround is to have multiple endpoints, one for each bot, delegating the work to a common class. E.g. you register `/bot1/api/messages/` for Bot1 and `/bot2/api/messages` for Bot2, each controller using the `BotAuthentication` attribute with the given bot's appId and secret. You can use the attribute like this:

```
[BotAuthentication(MicrosoftAppId="bot1AppId", MicrosoftAppPassword="bot1AppPwd")]
public class Bot1MessagesController : ApiController
...
```

Comment: I need to have a couple of bots, but I want to manage them with the same endpoint.

Comment: So you want multiple bot identities for the same endpoint. I believe your only option is to implement authentication yourself (check a list of Microsoft App IDs), as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: There's actually a workaround, see my updated answer.

Comment: But if I want to add bots over time I have to recompile each time in order to create new bots. I want to have only one controller to avoid writing new code and recompile the site!

Comment: Then you'll have to write your own authentication mechanism that uses a list of whitelisted appIds that you can read from a config file.