# Microsoft Bot Framework Multi-Tenant Credentials C#

Tags: c#, frameworks, bots, multi-tenant, credentials

**Background**

I've created a working bot in C# but I'm failing to expand it to be a multi-tenant bot.  I have created multiple bots in the Microsoft portal [using this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700009/is-it-possible-to-use-the-same-endpoint-for-several-microsoft-bots) to identify themselves from the messaging endpoint:

- https://example.com/api/messages/bot1
- https://example.com/api/messages/bot2
- https://example.com/api/messages/bot3

I can grab the LastSegment from the URL while in the MessagesController and store it in PrivateConversationData so I know which bot is talking in the current conversation.  I intended use this stored 'bot id' in order to retrieve the Microsoft AppId & Password from the web.config (the bot's credentials are stored as a series of custom entries and not the standard appSettings as that only works for a single bot).

**Credentials Problem**

The authentication works well (nearly) as [described here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2258) except when using async code with .ConfigureAwait(false) I can't get the HttpContext.Current as it becomes null when running on a different thread.  This means I can't get the authenticated user's credentials either by looking them up in the web.config or by calling GetCredentialsFromClaims() since I've lost the authenticated user.  If I use .ConfigureAwait(true) I just get deadlocks all over the place.

I have the credentials in the web.config but they are stored per bot and I need the 'bot id' from the URL above in order to get the credentials.

**Question**

The crux of the problem is: I need the URL to get the 'bot id' and I need the 'bot id' to get the credentials from the web.config but I can never reliably get access to the URL once I've passed a .ConfigureAwait(false) in the code.  On the flip side, I can't get the 'bot id' from the PrivateConversationData since I need the bot's credentials in order to load it.  A bit chicken and egg :-(

If anyone has any ideas of what I may be doing wrong or has an alternative approach to know which 'bot id' is currently executing I'd very much appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Can't we just set a context when the initial request came in and then use internally. i.e. when the initial request comes in, we do a lookup from the URL and then set up a new instance of the bot based on the URL and the credentials that you have in the config. This instance will be managed via IoC like Autofac and it will have a per-request lifetime scope. This will remove all your dependencies from the HttpContext throughout your process and is more reliable and available across threads too.

Comment: Can you add a code sample?  I understand the logic of what you're saying but I have no idea how to implement it.  I worked around the problem by moving this code from the static constructor:
`builder.Register(c => ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).GetCredentialsFromClaims())
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
`
To inside the Controller.Post method which allowed the anonymous method to still access the variables in the outer function.  Feels like a hack though...

Answer (score 0):

Please find below given the sample code.

```
public class StartUp {

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //Note: Initialize / register the Metadata Service that can bring the tenant details from the corresponding store
        builder.RegisterType<TenantMetadataService>().As<ITenantMetadataService>();

        //Note: This helps you in accessing the TenantMetadata from any constructor going forward after the below registry
        builder.Register(ti => TenantMetadata.GetTenantMetadataFromRequest()).InstancePerRequest();

        //TODO: Register the various services / controllers etc which may require the tenant details here
    }

}

public class TenantMetadata {

    public Guid TenantId { get;set; }
    public Uri TenantUrl { get;set; }
    public string TenantName { get;set; }

    public static TenantMetadata GetTenantMetadataFromRequest() {

        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        //TODO: If you have any header like TenantId coming from the request, you can read and use it
        var tenantIdFromRequestHeader = "";

        //TODO: There will be a lazy cache that keeps building the data as new tenant's login or use the application
        if(TenantCache.Contains(...))return TenantCache[Key];

        //TODO: Do a look-up from the above step and then construct the metadata
        var tenantMetadata = metadataSvc.GetTenantMetadata(...);
        //TODO: If the data match does not happen from the Step2, build the cache and then return the value.
        TenantCache.Add(key,tenantMetadata);
        return tenantMetadata;
    }
}
```

**Note**
The above code snippet uses the various service placeholders, cache and the other methods which will require to be used based on the designed application services. If you wish not to cache the tenant metadata, if it may contain some sensitive data, you can remove the caching implementation parts.

This implementation can be spread across all your web facing portals like your Web UI, Web Api and WebJobs etc so that it is same across all apps and it is easy to test and consume.

HTH.